# Server Selection in Activity

Tags: android, picker

I am trying to figure out how to design a page/activity where user will select the server at start of application.For ex. I have 2 servers, if he selects first server I call a certain url  and if he selects 2nd server I call a different url throughout the application.Shall I go with listview, spinner or is there some library out there to help me with such design?

Worth to note, the 2 server include country flag next to them.

Comment: I have used spinner for this feature. I had three servers dev,qa and prod.

Comment: use `listView`, that way your will have the option to add more servers anytime and customize the item with awesome view pretty simply

Comment: Spinner can be used for this purpose..

Comment: I prefer listview to spinner, because am making the user navigate faster.just a click on row goes to next screen, rather then clic the spinner choose a server and click submit.

Comment: you are the only one who should decide to use ListVIew, Spinner, or just add all servers to single Layout, or whatever. There is **no best way**